# SSH is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet - client is installed and path is correct

Tags: windows-10, powershell, openssh

The OpenSSH client is installed. To be sure everything was OK I removed it and reinstalled, but that made no difference.

[image: SSH client is installed]

The Path variable included OpenSSH.

[image: Path variables]

Windows Explorer shows that the folder C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH exists.

[image: Explorer folder for OpenSSH]

Via Powershell, this folder does not exist. And SSH does not work. Well, the OpenSSH server works, but the client not.

[image: Powershell SSH fails]

How can I start the OpenSSH client on this system?

Comment: use `Get-ChildItem` to get a listing of the dirs in system32, save it to a $Var. then use that to examine the exact name of the dir in question. you may have a non-printing char in the dir name. if that is not the case, then check the permissions on that dir - your account may not have the ability to see that dir.

Comment: Are you able to use the command with command prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the errors are caused by using Powershell(x86) instead of Powershell. When using Powershell(x86), I also get an error:

[image]

But if I use Powershell, then everything is normal

[image]

Powershell (x86) is the 32-bit version while Powershell is the 64-bit version as described [here](https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/):

> On a Windows 64-bit edition, you will find a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of PowerShell for backward compatibility purposes. If you type “PowerShell” on a Windows Start Screen, you will see “x86” behind the 32-bit versions of PowerShell and PowerShell ISE.

> By and large, the 64-bit and 32-bit PowerShell versions are compatible, and you shouldn’t notice much of a difference. Problems can arise if binaries are involved. For instance, if you want to extend PowerShell with snap-ins (compiled cmdlets), you have to ensure that you download the correct version. You can also run into problems if you want to instantiate an object of a 32-bit application (Microsoft Office, for example) with the 64-bit version of PowerShell.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks!

Comment: Still weird that Powershell, whether x86 or x86-64, can't find the "OpenSSH" folder. That shouldn't be dependent on Powershell process architecture, should it?

Comment: @amn I am of the opinion like you that finding whether a folder exists or not shouldn't depend on the architecture. But unfortunately, that's the case for Powershell.

Comment: It's not just Powershell, it turned out -- I got to the bottom of it. The answer is that "System32" is "virtual" for x86 processes -- the folder you're looking in is in reality `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64` and there is no "OpenSSH" there. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector